# How can I add a library path to a delphi project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have a couple precompiled (3rd party) libraries that I need to use in my project.

I can get it to build if I put foo.a in the root of my project folder, however, I have a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version of the library and I don't want to have to swap out `foo.a` with `foo.32.a` and `foo.64.a` every time I build each version of the application.

In this particular case I've put them in:

```
[myroot]\iOSDevice32\Debug\foo.a
[myroot]\iOSDevice32\Release\foo.a
```

and

```
[myroot]\iOSDevice64\Debug\foo.a
[myroot]\iOSDevice64\Release\foo.a
```

I could put it in the libary path (Tools -> Options -> Delphi Options -> Library -> Library Path); however, I want it to be specific to the project and relative to the root of the project folder (rather than hard coded to one location for all projects).

How can I tell Delphi/Embarcadero RAD Studio where to find these libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it in the project's search path (Project->Options->Delphi Compiler). You'll see a couple of examples there for using `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)`, which is a relative path to the project based on the target platform and build configuration.

Comment: When I do that, instead I get `[DCC Error] E2597 ld: library not found for -lc++`.  It seems to be overiding some existing search path instead of adding too it.

Comment: In this case I also tried it under Search path -> Value from "All configurations -All platforms" as well.

Comment: Correction.... I also had it in the System library root path (which looked like a likely place to put such a creation earlier in the day). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

goto tools-options-language-delphi-library

Comment: This is for setting the global/IDE library path, not for the project only.